# How do MIN() and MAX() work on CHAR/VARCHAR strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've been playing with the world database (InnoDB) found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) to gain more insight into MySQL.

I entered the following basic query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Name), MIN(Name), MAX(Name)
FROM Country
GROUP BY Continent
```

It seems that the way MIN() and MAX() work on the CHAR strings in Name is by alphabetical order, where A is the smallest value and Z is the greatest and so forth.

Can anyone explain what is going on behind the scenes and what values strings are being assigned for them to be sorted in such a way? What would happen with strings of both alphabetic characters and integers, or special characters?

Insight much appreciated.

Comment: it's using lexicographical order

Comment: What-s unclear to you? How B-Tree index is working? (If it was created, of course) - or how MySQL will compare strings?

Comment: @AlmaDo How MySQL compares strings, basically. I wanted to know what is going on to assign A a smaller value than B, for example, and where special characters and numbers fall on that scale.

Comment: Read about character sets and collation in documentation - here is a link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/globalization.html Generally a collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set, these rules defines that `A` < `B` and `q` > `w`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL string comparison, technically called *collation*, is locale-dependent. I suggest reading sections [10.1.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-general.html) on collation in general, [10.1.2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-mysql.html) on collation in MySQL and [10.1.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collations.html) about collation issues. On http://collation-charts.org/ you can find out details about the individual collations, e.g. the one called [`latin1_general_ci`](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_general_ci.html) (where `_ci` stands for case insensitive). The collation used when you call `MAX` and `MIN` should be the collation of the column in question, unless you specify a different collation using a formulation like [`MAX(Name COLLATE latin1_german2_ci)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html).