# MySQL MIN & MAX on alpha numeric column

Tags: mysql, max, min

Simple `MAX` query:

```
SELECT MAX(Group) FROM acme
```

Works fine on a numeric column.

Is it possible to use to this on an alpha-numeric column and ignore anything other than a number?

Comment: Refer to this answer on how MAX query is performed on strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581994/how-do-min-and-max-work-on-char-varchar-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes if you cast it before use like this

```
mysql> SELECT MAX(CAST("123" AS UNSIGNED));
+------------------------------+
| MAX(CAST("123" AS UNSIGNED)) |
+------------------------------+
|                          123 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT MAX(CAST("abc" AS UNSIGNED));
+------------------------------+
| MAX(CAST("abc" AS UNSIGNED)) |
+------------------------------+
|                            0 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT MAX(CAST("-123" AS SIGNED));
+-----------------------------+
| MAX(CAST("-123" AS SIGNED)) |
+-----------------------------+
|                        -123 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

replace your string column name with "abc" and modify query acording to your requirment

Comment: What if all numeric numbers are negative?

Comment: just use signed instead of unsigned

Comment: and what value of `MAX` do you expect?

Comment: @PM77-1 if you have a column with type=varchar and if it contain mix of integers and string using above query and modifing it acordingly you can get the max integer value in that column . is it clear to you