# In MySQL How do I join using a middle table to get the third table data if it exists?

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to word this question, so let me give an example of my problem.

I have:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
  FROM p
  LEFT JOIN q ON q.p_name = p.name
  LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = q.r_id AND r.type = 'bar'
  GROUP BY p.id
```

For the tables, assume I have

```
p
+--+-----+-----+
|id|name |info |
+--+-----+-----+
| 1|'ABC'|'Yes'|
| 2|'DEF'|'No' |
| 3|'GHI'|'Myb'|
| 4|'JKL'|'Yes'|
+--+-----+-----+

q
+------+----+
|p_name|r_id|
+------+----+
|'ABC' | 2  |
|'ABC' | 3  |
|'ABC' | 1  |
|'DEF' | 3  |
|'DEF' | 4  |
|'HIJ' | 2  |
|'HIJ' | 3  |
+------+----+

r
+--+-----+-----+
|id|name |type |
+--+-----+-----+
| 1|'Cya'|'bar'|
| 2|'Hi' |'grt'|
| 3|'Bye'|'foo'|
| 4|'Ltr'|'bar'|
+--+-----+-----+
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
desired output
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| p.id | p.name | p.info | r.name |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 'ABC'  | 'Yes'  | 'Cya'  |
| 2    | 'DEF'  | 'No'   | 'Ltr'  |
| 3    | 'GHI'  | 'Myb'  | NULL   |
| 4    | 'JKL'  | 'Yes'  | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

When I try the above query, I get the equivalent of this:

```
wrong output
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| p.id | p.name | p.info | r.name |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 'ABC'  | 'Yes'  | NULL   |
| 2    | 'DEF'  | 'No'   | NULL   |
| 3    | 'GHI'  | 'Myb'  | NULL   |
| 4    | 'JKL'  | 'Yes'  | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

When I try changing the query by adding a 'WHERE' clause to

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
  FROM p
  LEFT JOIN q ON q.p_name = p.name
  LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = q.r_id
WHERE r.type = 'bar'
  GROUP BY p.id
```

I get the following incorrect output

```
incorrect output
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| p.id | p.name | p.info | r.name |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 'ABC'  | 'Yes'  | 'Cya'  |
| 2    | 'DEF'  | 'No'   | 'Ltr'  |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

How do I get the desired output in a timely manner?

EDIT:
If I remove the 'GROUP BY', I am left with the following incorrect output:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| p.id | p.name | p.info | r.name |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 'ABC'  | 'Yes'  | NULL   |
| 1    | 'ABC'  | 'Yes'  | NULL   |
| 1    | 'ABC'  | 'Yes'  | 'Cya'  |
| 2    | 'DEF'  | 'No'   | NULL   |
| 2    | 'DEF'  | 'No'   | 'Ltr'  |
| 3    | 'GHI'  | 'Myb'  | NULL   |
| 3    | 'GHI'  | 'Myb'  | NULL   |
| 4    | 'JKL'  | 'Yes'  | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Something wrong with groupby logic i think. If you have in r record (2, 'Bye', 'bar') - how your output should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack the joins, like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
FROM p
  LEFT JOIN (q LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = q.r_id AND r.type = 'bar')
  ON q.p_name = p.name
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: i just ran the query and it returns NULL on all r_name rows

Comment: Use `q INNER JOIN r` and remove the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine, but the `group by` is unnecessary for the data you have provided:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
FROM p LEFT JOIN
     q
     ON q.p_name = p.name LEFT JOIN
     r
     ON r.id = q.r_id AND r.type = 'bar';
```

The `GROUP BY` should not be turning the last column from non-`NULL` to `NULL`.

Comment: Please look at the 'Edit' to the answer. When I remove the group by, it shows that I am getting all the rows for table 'q', but ignoring the data from table r

Answer (score 1):

I've imported your dataset to test my query and the following will give your "desired output":

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, MAX(r.id) as max_r_id
    FROM p
    LEFT JOIN q ON q.p_name = p.name
    LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = q.r_id AND r.type = 'bar'
    GROUP BY p.id
    ) AS result
INNER JOIN p ON p.id = result.id
LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = result.max_r_id
```

Comment: I should have noted that the real live version of this table, the 'type' in the 'r' table does not always have the type I need as the `MAX(r.id)` The real version of the table has over 13,000 rows, about 8 types and they're in a random order.

Comment: MAX can compare varchars or other column types too, it will result in selecting a non null value anyway, it seems is what you wanted. I've also made a test on a modified test schema, i've made r.id varchar and one of the id's a letter, it still returned non null values. Take a look of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581994/how-do-min-and-max-work-on-char-varchar-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: My apologies, I see now what is going on. I thought you were selecting type 'bar' because in the data the highest types are 'bar', but instead it appears that you're just choosing the max when the 'type=bar' is found

Answer (score 0):

This is one of few cases where i would consider to use a RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
FROM r
JOIN q ON q.r_id = r.id
RIGHT JOIN p ON p.name = q.p_name AND r.type = 'bar';
```

If you care about performance ..

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, r.name
FROM p
JOIN q ON q.p_name = p.name
JOIN r ON r.id = q.r_id 
WHERE r.type = 'bar'

UNION ALL

SELECT p.id, p.name, p.info, NULL
FROM p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM r
    JOIN q ON q.r_id = r.id
    WHERE q.p_name = p.name
      AND r.type = 'bar'
);
```

http://rextester.com/OMD47103